# Fetch data from moved pemanently (301) API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to fetch data from API. In command line with CURL works but I want to do it with `fetch()` or axios in ReactJS. I tried really hard without success.

```
curl -i -X GET -u user:pass -H "Accept:application/json" "http://sample.api.net/list"
status 301 - moved permanently
Location: https://sample.api.net:443/list
```

With `L` next to `-i` redirects me and everything is OK.

```
curl -iL -X GET -u user:pass -H "Accept:application/json" "http://sample.api.net/list"
status 200 OK
It works
```

I tried with fetch and axios but always giving me 301 Moved and failed to fetch. Also I need authorization.

```
fetch("http://sample.api.net/list", {
  redirect: "follow",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: "Basic fdfdgdfgfd",
  },
})
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Doesn't work :(

Comment: dont know if this is the case but sometimes chrome caches redirects. try removing them. might help

Comment: Thank you. I think that's not the case. Still the same.